# Is it commonly considered erroneous to place "much" after "and", when talking about myself?

Tags: word-usage

Is it commonly considered erroneous to place "much" after "and", when talking about myself?

---

**My phrasing:**

> well experienced with content management systems, and **much** interested in E-commerce.

**Commentators phrasing:**

> well experienced with content management systems, and **very** interested in E-commerce.

I am not sure who's more accurate than both of us, in regards to what's common and accepted in English.

Comment: In my view, "much" works better here than "very" but at the same time, how is that not purely a personal style choice, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing to do with whether it is about yourself, or after *and*.

*Much* is not generally used with a positive adjective (i.e. one that is not comparative) in a positive context. So if I search for "-not much -j*" (that is, a word which is not *not*, followed by *much*, followed by an adjective), in both the British National Corpus and the Corpus of Contemporary American English, almost all the instances are with a comparative adjective.

It *is* used in a negative context ("not much"), and with comparative adjectives ("much easier"). There is also an idiomatic use of *very much*, in the sense *definitely*: a common example is "very much aware".

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down the grammar of this sentence, "interested" is an adjective. So, "much" or "very" should be used as an adverb. Very is a flexible adverb, it can be used to compliment an adjective, adverb, or a noun. But, much is somewhat restrictive and is used to mainly to modify comparative adjectives.

> Consider the two phrases "very big" and "much bigger" try to swap the places of "very" and "much". Very sounds better in a standalone statement and much sounds better in a comparison.

Much is the preferred choice if your sentence were "I'm much interested in E-commerce over [Brick and mortar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_and_mortar)."
BTW, your sentence would be much more accurate if it were,

> Well experienced in content management systems, and very interested in E-commerce.

"In" instead of "with". You mostly work in a CMS not work with it.